# How to calculate the coordinates of every vertex of retrieved pdf image

Tags: java, pdf, coordinates, pdfbox, affinetransform

I want to calculate coordinates of vertexes for extracted images

I retrieved images using PDFBOX. Afterwards I started examining matrix

```
Matrix ctmNew = getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix();
```

I did many tries to determine coordinates of every angle but couldn't invent generic solution for (normal image, flipped, rotated etc.)

```
public class StreamEngine extends PDFStreamEngine {

    private ImageFile buildImage(final PDXObject element) throws IOException {
        final PDRectangle cropBox = getCurrentPage().getCropBox();
        final PDRectangle mediaBox = getCurrentPage().getMediaBox();
        final PDImageXObject image = (PDImageXObject) element;
        Matrix ctmNew = getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix();
        final double imageWidth = ctmNew.getScalingFactorX();
        final double imageHeight = ctmNew.getScalingFactorY();
        final double bottom = mediaBox.getHeight() - ctmNew.getTranslateY(); //I need coordinates started from top
        final double left = ctmNew.getTranslateX();
        final ImageFile imageFile = new ImageFile();
        imageFile.setImageFormat("png");
        imageFile.setImageHeight(imageHeight);
        imageFile.setImageWidth(imageWidth);
        imageFile.setLeft(left);
        imageFile.setPageWidth(cropBox.getWidth());
        imageFile.setPageHeight(cropBox.getHeight());
        imageFile.setBottom(bottom);
// do proper calculation here
        return imageFile;
    }
}
```

Currently I don't receive right coordinates for flipped + rotated image. And every time I adjust somehow the code for particular case, previous case is spoiled.

Please do not fix the code above, just give me some advice how can I calculate the coordinates.

[image: scheme of the data required]

Comment: Simply apply the transformation to the four corners of the unit square and you'll have the four corners of your image. To these coordinates apply any further transformations you need, e.g. for your "I need coordinates started from top".

Comment: http://i67.tinypic.com/axdvdl.png I need just calculate beta from this pic, please advise and the question is done

Answer (score 0):

The answer was pretty straightforward
Link: https://code-industry.net/masterpdfeditor-help/transformation-matrix/

```
    private void calculateCoordinates(final ImageFile imageFile, final Matrix ctmNew) {

        double llx = calculateXCoordinate(ctmNew, 0, 0);
        double lly = calculateYCoordinate(ctmNew, 0, 0);

        double ulx = calculateXCoordinate(ctmNew, 0, 1);
        double uly = calculateYCoordinate(ctmNew, 0, 1);

        double lrx = calculateXCoordinate(ctmNew, 1, 0);
        double lry = calculateYCoordinate(ctmNew, 1, 0);

        double urx = calculateXCoordinate(ctmNew, 1, 1);
        double ury = calculateYCoordinate(ctmNew, 1, 1);

        final double left = Math.min(Math.min(llx, ulx), Math.min(lrx, urx));
        final double top = Math.max(Math.max(lly, uly), Math.max(lry, ury));

        final double right = Math.max(Math.max(llx, ulx), Math.max(lrx, urx));
        final double bottom = Math.min(Math.min(lly, uly), Math.min(lry, ury));

        imageFile.setTop(top);
        imageFile.setBottom(bottom);
        imageFile.setLeft(left);
        imageFile.setRight(right);
    }

    private double calculateXCoordinate(final Matrix ctmNew, final double x, final double y) {
        double a = ctmNew.getValue(0, 0);
        double c = ctmNew.getValue(1, 0);
        double e = ctmNew.getValue(2, 0);
        return a * x + c * y + e;
    }

    private double calculateYCoordinate(final Matrix ctmNew, final double x, final double y) {
        double b = ctmNew.getValue(0, 1);
        double d = ctmNew.getValue(1, 1);
        double f = ctmNew.getValue(2, 1);
        return b * x + d * y + f;
    }
```